# Create migration from schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I want to drop a table in a large Rails application with hundreds of migrations.

Preferably, I want to create the migration file in a way that can be rolled back.

Is there a way to more or less copy the current schema for that table into the migration, so when I drop it there's still the option to roll back?

I know this migration format:

```
class DropSupplierTerms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    drop_table :supplier_terms do |t|
       t.field :name
       t.field :name
       t.field :name
       t.field :name
       t.field :name
       t.field :name
  end
end
```

The `schema.rb` code looks similar, is it possible to simply paste the whole schema table into the `drop` block?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can copy and paste from `schema.rb`**

Remember that data itself wont rollback though